# Xcode stuck in loop with Signing Certificate

Tags: macos, mojave, xcode

My xcode managed signing profile is having some problems. XCode is stuck in a loop that begins with "Waiting to repair"

I am using a non-developer account. App signing was working previously with this Apple ID.

This is the entire loop:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]

After the loop reaches "Creating provisioning profile" it returns to the status shown in the first image.

I'd like to resolve the Signing Certificate issue so that I can sign apps again.

XCode 11.3.1

macOS 10.14.6

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?